# How to access from Array of list in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

**output:**

```
 [{'name': 'person',
   'percentage_probability': 52.69544720649719,
   'box_points': array([1165, 1132, 1197, 1212])}].
```

How to access values in box_points(Inside array)?

I want output as: 1165

I tried to import array library, convert to string and slice it but no use.

Please help

Comment: what's the type of array?  if using python system library `array`, the first parameter should be the typecode.

Comment: Array is output of a model.

Answer (score 1):

There is no in-built method in python as `array` so you need to use it as list:

```
item_no = [{'name': 'person',
   'percentage_probability': 52.69544720649719,
   'box_points': [1165, 1132, 1197, 1212]}]

print(item_no[0]['box_points'][0])
```

**Explanation**:

You have a list of dictionaries. First access the list element which is `dict`. Access `dict` element using specific `key` and as the value of `box_point` is array access it using 0th element.

Comment: Thank you Akshay. The output of model is in this form. I want to access from this form itself. I know what you said but i am unable to convert the output to that form.

Comment: Can you show us what is the output of `print(type(item_no[0]['box_points']))` ?

Comment: output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/MY_TOOL/video/try7(csv_creation)/tool_csv.py", line 9, in <module>
    'box_points': array([1159, 1130, 1191, 1211])}]
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: It's hard to understand how you getting an `array`.

Comment: @PratishaPadishalwar just assign the value: `item_no[0]['box_points']=item_no[0]['box_points'][0]` and `print(item_no)`  you should get: `[{'name': 'person', 'percentage_probability': 52.69544720649719, 'box_points': 1165}]`